Bibliotherapy in the treatment of depersonalization
Sometimes very strange things happen to people's psyches.  Depersonalization is one such phenomenon.
Depersonalization is a painful experience of one’s own change, change in one’s own mental processes, one’s own “I”: patients complain that they have become “something different from before”, “lost emotions, feelings”, “lost their own “Entity”, lost their  talents.
And I wondered if a psychotherapist always resorts to the use of medications to treat his patients with depersonalization. Question specifically mentions art-therapy as a promising source of useful thoughts, settings and attitudes that will help the patient look at things from the right angle and get him out of this monstrous syndrome.
Results of my searches: I did not find a systematic presentation of the practical application of art-therapy (bibliotherapy in particular) for the treatment of depersonalization.  There was only “everyday” advice and advice from ordinary people.  The list of recommended literature included Albert Camus - L'Etranger, Jean-Paul Sartre - Nausea, books by Franz Kafka.
What I would like to know: what characteristics and, more importantly in my opinion, what content should a book have in order to help (or provide significant support) in the treatment of a patient with depersonalization?  Can reading books by a patient with depersonalization be dangerous, that is, cause him harm?  Please also share your practical experience if you have one.
28 June 2024: A very interesting question unfortunately remained unanswered.
